# Add / Remove rows in a table and modify dynamically first column cell rowspan

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a table with five rows. 
The user can add a row by pressing the + button on each row. The new row is inserted below the row where the user clicked the + button and i want to change the rowspan of the first cell of the row where the user clicked so that it grows/shrinks accordingly.

It's working ok when I add a new row, but it has problem when adding other rows or when deleting rows.

Here is a fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/UP262/1/

What am i doing wrong?It has to do with the manipulation of rowspan, of course.

EDIT - The problem is that when i .clone() the row when adding a second row or removing it I'm cloning a row that hasn't the first 'td'...i need to get the first row of the set dynamically. How can i do that?

EDIT 2 - now the + is working, here is the edited code: http://jsfiddle.net/UP262/5/
Still need help with the minus

And here is my html/jquery code:

```
  <table id="tableRealizzazione" style="border:1px solid;" class="display">
    <thead>
      <tr bgcolor="#B8D3E8" style:="">
        <th width="10%">Costi gestione</th>

        <th width="60%">descrizione</th>

        <th width="10%" align="center">Totale (migliaia euro)</th>

        <th width="10%">Azioni</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>Locazione</td>

        <td><input type="text" value="" id="DescrizioneLocazione" name=
        "DescrizioneLocazione[]" /></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="text" class="totaliCostiGestione" value="0" id=
        "TotaleLocazione" name="TotaleLocazione[]" /></td>

        <td align="left"><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" value="+" id=
        "aggiungi" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="odd">
        <td>Personale</td>

        <td><input type="text" value="" id="DescrizionePersonale" name=
        "DescrizionePersonale[]" /></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="text" class="totaliCostiGestione" value="0" id=
        "TotalePersonale" name="TotalePersonale[]" /></td>

        <td align="left"><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" value="+" id=
        "aggiungi" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="even">
        <td>Consumi e manutenzione</td>

        <td><input type="text" value="" id="DescrizioneConsumiManutenzione" name=
        "DescrizioneConsumiManutenzione" /></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="text" class="totaliCostiGestione" value="0" id=
        "TotaleConsumiManutenzione" name="TotaleConsumiManutenzione" /></td>

        <td align="left"><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" value="+" id=
        "aggiungi" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="odd">
        <td>Assicurazioni e simili</td>

        <td><input type="text" value="" id="DescrizioneAssicurazioniSimili" name=
        "DescrizioneAssicurazioniSimili" /></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="text" class="totaliCostiGestione" value="0" id=
        "TotaleAssicurazioniSimili" name="TotaleAssicurazioniSimili" /></td>

        <td align="left"><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" value="+" id=
        "aggiungi" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="even">
        <td>Marketing</td>

        <td><input type="text" value="" id="DescrizioneMarketing" name=
        "DescrizioneMarketing" /></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="text" class="totaliCostiGestione" value="0" id=
        "TotaleMarketing" name="TotaleMarketing" /></td>

        <td align="left"><input type="button" style="width: 50px;" value="+" id=
        "aggiungi" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Totale</td>

        <td></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="0" id=
        "TotaleGestione" name="TotaleGestione" style=
        "background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" /></td>

        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

    $('#aggiungi').live('click', function(){
        debugger;
        var thisRow = $(this).parent().parent();
        $(this).parent().parent().clone(true).insertAfter(thisRow);
        $(this).val("-");
        $(this).attr("id","remove");
        var nextRow = thisRow.next();
        currRowSpan = thisRow.children(":first").attr("rowspan");
        thisRow.children(":first").attr("rowspan", currRowSpan+1);
        nextRow.find('input:not(#aggiungi)').val("");
        nextRow.children(":first").remove();
        });

    $('#remove').live('click', function(){
        var prevRow = $(this).parent().parent().next();
        currRowSpan = prevRow.children(":first").attr("rowspan");
        prevRow.children(":first").attr("rowspan", currRowSpan-1);
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
```

Comment: It's hard to see what the actual effect should be here. Can you explain by a screenshot what result you want? Again, if possible, please use english in your examples so we can better understand.

Comment: If you look at the new fiddle i achieved what i wanted with the + button. I'd like to have the same effect with the - button!Sorry if my english it's not good, i didn't translate html attributes because they are only "names", but if it helps i translate them too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh, so late..
http://jsfiddle.net/3SKXk/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll look how you've done it, my code surely needs some improvement!

Comment: I think you code is nicer than mine! So i acccept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not the problem, but better than doing `parent().parent().`... it is better to do `.closest('tr')` to find the row element.